# Error 0xE0434F4D as 'Last Run Result' of a Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: scheduled-task, windows

Hallo,

i get the error 0xE0434F4D as 'Last Run Result' of a Scheduled Task on Windows Server 2008.
I have checked the permissions of the user that is running the scheduled task,
and the user does have the necessary permissions.

So what could be the problem, and what does this error mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to run an .NET program from a network share (or better UNC path?). Then this is a security issue. Copy your program locally and run it there.

When you run the program without the Task Scheduler only from the GUI, does it crash, too? If so have you installed the correct .NET Framework version?

Comment: This helped me - I accidentally checked "Do not store password", but the app I was running had to copy an extract to a network share. As soon as I unchecked that, everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just set working directory into the action tab for you task. Maybe you using parameters for you programm, all files must be in the directory at the same level

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of answers posted here worked. Assembly was launched locally under windows XP, no obvious issues with permissions.

I examined installed .NET version (well-known registry subtree `HKLM\SOFTWARE\NET Framework Setup\NDP`) and found that subkey `v3.5\SP` (ServicePack) is NOT at `1`. It means that .NET 3.5 is installed, but **not the latest** released version (SP1). After [downloading v3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25150), installing and restarting the PC, the entire problem disappeared. So the key was "*not just any .NET 3.5, but latest .NET 3.5 must be present*".

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the person who is scheduling the task does not have the operating system Administrator role.